# Ignore option in jquery validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, unobtrusive-validation

I want  to validate some hidden element in `jquery`

```
<label class="btn col-1" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <input id="Cert1" asp-for="Cert1.CertImageFile" onchange="SetImagePath('#CertImage1','#Cert1')" type="file" class="fileInput" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" hidden>
    <img src="~/images/browse.png" width="23" />
    <small><span asp-validation-for="Cert1.CertImageFile" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span></small>
</label>


function validateForm() {
                // This function deals with validation of the form fields
                var x, y, i, valid = true;
                x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input,select");
                
                // A loop that checks every input feld in the current tab:
                var form = $("#regForm");
                for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    // If a field is not valid...
                    if (!form.validate({
                        ignore: ':hidden:not(.fileInput)'
                    }).element(y[i])) {
                        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                        y[i].className += " invalid";
                        // and set the current valid status to false
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                
                return valid; // return the valid status
            }
```

but ignore option doesn't work even when I set `ignore: ''` to replace all ignoring option it still doesn't vlidate hidden fields

Comment: It should be inverted, .fileInput:not(:hidden), that means that it should watch all the ".fileInput" that aren't :hidden

Comment: I want that file input get validated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Unobtrusive plugin calls validate() when the document get loaded and sets options to defaults. a validator then cached and any further calls to validate will ignore new options and return the cached validator

so I add this line before my loop validation and it worked

```
$("#regForm").validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(.fileInput)";
```